# How to scrape only texts from specific HTML elements?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with selecting the appropriate items from the list.

For example - I want to omit "1." then the first "5" (as in the example)
Additionally, I would like to write a condition that the letter "W" should be changed to "WIN".

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS2
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.flashscore.pl/druzyna/ajax/8UOvIwnb/tabela/")
sleep(10)
page = driver.page_source
soup = BS2(page,'html.parser')
content = soup.find('div',{'class':'ui-table__body'})
content_list = content.find_all('span',{"table__cell table__cell--value"})

res = []
for i in content:
    line = i.text.split()[0]
    if re.search('Ajax', line):
        res.append(line)
print(res)
```

results

```
['1.Ajax550016:315?WWWWW']
```

I need

```
Ajax;5;5;0;16;3;W;W;W;W;W
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to select your elements more specific:

```
for e in soup.select('.ui-table__row'):
```

Iterate the `ResultSet` and `decompose()` unwanted tag:

```
e.select_one('.wld--tbd').decompose()
```

Extract texts with `stripped_strings` and `join()` them to your expected string:

```
data.append(';'.join(e.stripped_strings))
```

##### Example

Also making some replacements, based on `dict` just to demonstrate how this would work, not knowing `R` or `P`.

```
...
soup = BS2(page,'html.parser')
data = []

for e in soup.select('.ui-table__row'):
    e.select_one('.wld--tbd').decompose()
    e.select_one('.tableCellRank').decompose()
    e.select_one('.table__cell--points').decompose()
    e.select_one('.table__cell--score').string = ';'.join(e.select_one('.table__cell--score').text.split(':'))
    pattern = {'W':'WIN','R':'RRR','P':'PPP'}
    data.append(';'.join([pattern.get(i,i) for i in e.stripped_strings]))
data
```

To only get result for *Ajax*:

```
data = []

for e in soup.select('.ui-table__row:-soup-contains("Ajax")'):
    e.select_one('.wld--tbd').decompose()
    e.select_one('.tableCellRank').decompose()
    e.select_one('.table__cell--points').decompose()
    e.select_one('.table__cell--score').string = ';'.join(e.select_one('.table__cell--score').text.split(':'))
    pattern = {'W':'WIN','R':'RRR','P':'PPP'}
    data.append(';'.join([pattern.get(i,i) for i in e.stripped_strings]))
data
```

##### Output

Based on actually data it may differ from questions example.

```
['Ajax;6;6;0;0;21;3;WIN;WIN;WIN;WIN;WIN']
```

Comment: How i ask about only one team ? "AJAX" and there is only one result on score ajax has 16 and it is 16:3

Comment: Not sure about `16:3` you expected `16;3` - To get only the Ajax Team check edit in answer. If this not answer your additional question,it would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus

Answer (score 0):

you had the right start by using bs4 to find the table div, but then you gave up and just tried to use re to extract from the text.  as you can see that's not going to work. Here is a simple way to hack and get what you want.  I keep grabinn divs from the table div you find, and the grab the text of the next eight divs after finding Ajax.  then I do some dirty string manipulation thing because the WWWWW is all in the same toplevel div.

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS2
from time import sleep

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.flashscore.pl/druzyna/ajax/8UOvIwnb/tabela/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
page = driver.page_source
soup = BS2(page,'html.parser')
content = soup.find('div',{'class':'ui-table__body'})
content_list = content.find_all('span',{"table__cell table__cell--value"})

res = []
found = 0
for i in content.find('div'):
    line = i.text.split()[0]
    if re.search('Ajax', line):
        found = 8
    if found:
        found -= 1
        res.append(line)
# change field 5 into separate values and skip field 6
res = res[:4] +res[5].split(':') + res[7:]
# break the last field into separate values and drop the first '?'
res = res[:-1] + [ i for i in res[-1]][1:]
print(";".join(res))
```

returns

```
Ajax;5;5;0;16;3;W;W;W;W;W
```

This works, but it is very brittle, and will break as soon as the website changes their content.  you should put in a lot of error checking.  I also replaced the sleep with a wait call, and added chromedrivermamager, which allows me to use selenium with chrome.

Comment: line = i.text.split()[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: maybe the implicitl_wait call doesn't work properly for you.  you can try to add the sleep call again.  this code still works for me.